# Custom modification of new bean instances in Quarkus

Tags: spring, quarkus

I need to scan new beans for the presence of an annotation when they are added to the application context. I need something like BeanPostProcessor from Spring.

Comment: Since bean discovery in Quarkus happens during application build, there's no runtime API for this. However, the Quarkus extension API should give you a lot of what you need. See https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-integration

Comment: What exactly do you intend to do?

Comment: My 2 questions are related, I need to scan all the beans for the presence of an annotation, and then after adding them to the context, call the method and pass the scan results.